# Maven POM <testResources> does not work when <sourceDirectory> Is setup

Tags: java, pom.xml

I am working with IntellIJ IDE and I am trying to set up the project structure from the POM because is a kind of annoying set up every time when I downloaded the project directly from IntellIJ, I've set up the following in the POM under the build tag and it is almost working

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

The missing part is the "testResources", this works fine when the tag "sourceDirectory" is not in the POM, but when I set up all of this together this does not work, any ideas or recommendation here?

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to override the directory layout? It is usually better to just stick with the standard.

Comment: because I have a custom project structure, src > main & src > test

Comment: Yes, but why do you have a custom project structure? Do you have a really good reason for it?

Comment: Well, I am a collaborator in that project, the project structure was defined like this, the only thing that I am trying to do is to set up the project structure in the POM

Comment: i would leave that project in your place... who places sources under `src/test`?? (they are *not serious*!;)

Comment: ...and probably IntelliJ(not even maven) has problems to define a "source folder" inside another one. (srct/test/resources is under /src/test ..and what if you had a package named "resources"??)